# Is it acceptable to no longer support javascript-disabled or non-ajax browsers for secured applications?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, cross-browser

I'm curious about the current trend these days for ajax-applications. Is it acceptable to simply build an ajax application the best you can make it and simply ignore browsers that don't support ajax (assuming this a secured part of the site... not the public part)?

I am not talking about corporate intranets where you can reasonably control the browsers being used - but sites that people pay a monthly rate for. It's not quite public, but it's not controlled either.

It seems that the more you make your ajax application "kick ass", the harder it is to support the old model of doing things. The two models diverge further and further apart from each other that you're basically writing 2 UIs/controllers for everything in your system. Maybe in some cases you are writing 2 views too.

I'm the only developer working on this particular project. Having to double my efforts actually seems like a waste of time. I think I am better off building the product I want, and if it's successful, maybe go back and add the non-ajax stuff later (if at all).

The project's unique selling point - it's core domain - has a lot to do with the way I'm going to incorporate ajax. Frankly, supporting the non-ajax stuff isn't really that important to me. The software that doesn't support ajax is basically going to be a copy of what people are already using. The reason people would use this software is because it's a lot easier to use and it's lot more fun to use.

If people want the non-ajax version, there's already a lot of products out there that do that. I'm thinking it's smart to just say "screw it... that's a market I'm just going to ignore... and I'm going to bank on the fact that my product might eventually overtake them anyway."

Given this scenario, would it be reasonable to simply not support browsers with javascript disabled? If I did that, what things would I need to worry about, besides customers using older browsers and having problems?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do think this trend is coming, but in general I'm not sure it's quite here just yet.

Comment: In my experience: the more interactive your web page is (i.e. the closer it comes to being a "web application"), the more acceptable it becomes to only support JS-enabled browsers. Also: please don't mix "JS is disabled in the browser" with "JS is not supported in the browser": they are quite distinct cases and the latter is becomming more and more uncommon.

Comment: @alex: Well, part of this question is if I decide to not support the non-ajax browsers, what things will I need to concern myself with to make this deployment successful? Like technical things.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: What would be way to deal with people who have it disabled? Just show a screen saying to enable it? :/

Comment: Filament Group would say something along the lines of "Hell no." and then continue along with graceful degradation etc.

Comment: A perspective here: http://www.punkchip.com/2011/03/why-support-javascript-disabled/. This gives me de ja vous from the kind of debate we had about DHTML in the early noughties, just before the likes of Web Standards / Unobtrusive JS. For me, forking approach for one sort of app doest support the semantic web or any ideals of device neutrality.

Comment: @trickwallett - that's a good article. Maybe I should just deploy the application using javascript only... and then see my statistics. If the number is > 1%, then perhaps I add the functionality in. If it's less than 1%, then it shows I made the correct choice.

Comment: I don't think her final conclusion in that article is correct though. The site I'm building - there's no basic HTML alternative. It doesn't exist. I can't do what she's suggesting. I would have to code it entirely differently... and the views will be totally different as well. I think her approach works for some sites - even most sites - but not something fresh and revolutionary, which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can safely assume all of your users have JavaScript enabled or are able (and willing) to enable it for your site, you can require JavaScript.

However, you should still provide a meaningful, well-looking error page for those who do not have JavaScript. You could even add a guide how to enable (or allow - e.g. via NoScript) JavaScript for the site.

Comment: Well, I don't know if I can *safely assume* :) I'm not sure. I might have to get statistics. My guess is that lots will have javascript enabled. I'm looking at it like this: I can spend X hours to support 99% users, and .7(X) hours to support 1% more users. Is it worth it when I am just doing the project myself? I starting to think that the answer to this question is "no". So yeah, probably giving them an error screen that helps them out is the best option.